# Problems accessing state in React-native with redux app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

So I'm new to `Redux` and am having problems accessing the `STATE`. When I add the `constructor()` method into my `Component (Welcome)` I get a `Cannot find module /Welcome` error. I'll paste my code below as I'm really struggling!

I'm simply trying to print out the text state!

#### Components/Welcome/index.jsx

```
import React, { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';


const Welcome = React.createClass({ //() => (

   constructor() {
        super(props, context);
        console.log("context", this.context);
    }

    render () {
        // state = super(props);
        // console.log(state);
        return (
        <View style={ styles.container }>
            <Text style={ styles.welcome }>
                React Native Redux Starter Kit
            </Text>
            <Text style={ styles.instructions }>
                { this.props.text }
            </Text>
            <Text style={ styles.instructions }>
                Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
                Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
            </Text>
        </View>
        )
    }
// );
});
```

#### containers/app.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from 'configStore';
import ExNavigator from '@exponent/react-native-navigator';
import routes from 'routes';

export default class App extends Component{



   /**
     * Render
     *
     * @return {jsx} Render <Provider /> component
     */
    render(){
        return (
            <Provider store={ configureStore() }>
                <ExNavigator
                  initialRoute={ routes.getHomeRoute() }
                  style={{ flex: 1 }}
                  sceneStyle={{ paddingTop: 64 }} />
            </Provider>
        );
    }

}
```

#### reducers/bar.jsx:

This is setting the state of text = "testssters". I'm trying to print this out in my component.

```
import Immutable from 'immutable';
import { BAR } from 'constants/ActionTypes';

const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
    text: "hi"
});

export default function bar(state = {
    text: "testssters",
  }, action) 
{
    switch(action.type) {
        case BAR:
            state = state;
            break;
    }

    return state;
}
```

#### routes.jsx:

```
const routes = {};

    /**
     * Homepage
     *
     */

     // Shows the homepage (Welcome/index.js)
    routes.getHomeRoute = () => ({
        getSceneClass() {
            return require('Welcome/').default;
        },
        getTitle() {
            return 'Welcome';
        }
    });
```

#### configStore.jsx:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as reducers from 'reducers/';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
    // Add remote-redux-devtools
)(createStore);

export default function configureStore() {
    return createStoreWithMiddleware(combineReducers(reducers));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`React.createClass()` expects an object and not a function.

If you're using `createClass()`, in order to set an initial state use `getInitialState`.

```
const Welcome = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return { myState: 1 };
    },
    render: function () {}
});
```

If you want to use ES6 classes then the same would look like this

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { myState: 1 };
    }
    render() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I'm wondering how I can access the ```state = {
    text: "testssters",
  }``` from the reducer inside the component??

Comment: If you're using a local component state you just refer it to `this.state.text`, if you're using Redux state, you'll have to use `this.props.text` and then have Redux inject it into your props through the provider and `connect`.

Comment: I dont mean to be a pain, but could you maybe make a sample? I've been having so much trouble trying to do that! :/

Comment: This link here will help you alot! http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Comment: I've tried everything! I can't pass the store in ```<Provider store={ configureStore() }>``` down to my ```Welcome``` component. Any idea to how I can do this given my code above? Sorry to bug you again!!